# I just created a Python script. I am trying to run it on my windows computer. It does not work

Tags: python, compilation, raw-input

I created a python script named "script.py":

```
variable=raw_input("what is your name: ")

print "welcome",variable
```

Now I am trying to run it on my computer so that it prompts me with "What is your name" and then I can write my name, and then it greets me. How do I do this? I tried compiling the script in cmd using the command **python script.py** but nothing happens.

**Edit:**
[image: When I enter **python script.py** nothing happens]

I also changed the code so that it would be compatible with python 3.8(the version I downloaded)

Comment: What is the error that is written in the cmd prompt? When you have installed Python on your machine, did you check the box "Add Python to PATH"? When you run the cmd command `python script.py`, are you in the same directory of the `script.py` file?

Comment: I have not installed python on my computer. I did not think is necessary

Comment: I installed it now, went to cmd and did the same thing. nothing happens. And yes. I am in the same directory in cmd as the python script file.

Comment: What is the error that is written in the cmd prompt?

Comment: There is no error message. When I press enter, nothing happens. It's just a new blank cmd line.

Comment: I forgot to check the box "Add Python to Path". I reinstalled and did it and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed a version of python later than 3 (3.6, 3.7, 3.8), then you have to use these `input()` and `print()` functions:

```
variable=input("what is your name: ")
print("welcome " + variable)
```

The `print` function you used is for the previuos Python versions (2.7)